# Frequency list from multiple columns in dataframe based on restriction

Tags: r, frequency

I have a df containing words (columns w1, w2, etc.) and their durations, some of which are NA (columns d1, d2, etc.), like this one:

```
set.seed(47)
df <- data.frame(
  w1 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T)),
  w2 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T)),
  w3 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T)),
  w4 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T)),
  d1 = c(rep(NA, 3), round(rnorm(7),3)),
  d2 = c(round(rnorm(6),3), NA, round(rnorm(3),3)),
  d3 = c(round(rnorm(2),3), rep(NA,2), round(rnorm(6),3)),
  d4 = c(round(rnorm(1),3), NA, round(rnorm(8),3))
)
```

```
   w1 w2 w3 w4     d1     d2     d3     d4
1   D  A  A  C     NA -2.322 -0.693 -0.488
2   B  C  C  B     NA -1.967  0.261     NA
3   D  A  C  B     NA  0.028     NA  -0.92
4   D  C  A  A -1.566  0.484     NA  0.898
5   C  C  C  D  0.249  0.144  0.507 -0.356
6   C  D  B  B  -0.34   -1.2  0.564  1.032
7   B  B  A  A  0.417     NA  0.061  0.664
8   B  A  A  D -0.326  0.885 -0.109   0.97
9   C  A  C  B  -0.89  0.887 -0.155  1.676
10  D  B  D  C -1.608  0.001   0.95  1.988
```

What I'd like to get is a single frequency list of all those word *tokens* that are *not* NA in the corresponding duration column. So, for example, "D" in Column `w1` is NA in `d1` so this token should not be included in the frequency count.
How is this programmed in base R, ideally in a single line of code?

Comment: I put in a `set.seed()` so the random data is reproducible. Using that sample data, could you say what your desired output is? I don't really get what you mean when you say "not NA in **any** of the duration columns". Do you mean you only want to count rows like row 5 that have no NAs? Or Is it word-specific, `d1` is NA in the first row, it corresponds to `w1 = "D"`, so all Ds are excluded? Or something else?

Comment: Also, one-line solutions will be pretty difficult with your input. The way you've defined your data using `"NA"` instead of `NA` means even your duration columns are `factor` class, which makes them difficult to work with. Is this the case in your real data, or are they numeric?

Comment: See the edit I've made; this hopefully clarifies the issue. In the real data, NAs are numeric.

Comment: Okay, I've removed the quotes from you `NA`s so they are numeric.

Comment: `table(unlist(replace(df[paste0("w", 1:4)], is.na(df[paste0("d", 1:4)]), NA)))` doesn't seem to get rid of those vaues that are NA in the durations columns:  A  B  C  D 
10 10 12  8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring values that are `NA` in their corresponding columns:

```
table(unlist(replace(df[paste0("w", 1:4)], is.na(df[paste0("d", 1:4)]), NA)))
#  B  C  D  A 
#  7 11  6  9
```

```
# Alternate approach
table(unlist(df[1:4])[!is.na(unlist(df[5:8]))])
#  B  C  D  A 
#  7 11  6  9
```

---

Completely omitting values that have NA anywhere:

It's 3 lines, but I'd do it like this:

```
all_words = unlist(df[1:4])
na_words = all_words[is.na(unlist(df[5:8]))]
table(droplevels(all_words[! all_words %in% na_words]))
# < table of extent 0 >
```

You could do it in a single line, but it's much uglier, very hard to tell what's going on.

```
table(droplevels(unlist(df[1:4])[! unlist(df[1:4]) %in% unlist(df[1:4])[is.na(unlist(df[5:8]))]]))
```

For the given sample data, it gives a table of length 0 because all of the unique words have an `NA` somewhere. If you change the input data to use more letters, we get non-empty results:

```
set.seed(47)
df2 <- data.frame(
  w1 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10, replace = T)),
  w2 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10, replace = T)),
  w3 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10, replace = T)),
  w4 = c(sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10, replace = T)),
  d1 = c(rep(NA, 3), round(rnorm(7),3)),
  d2 = c(round(rnorm(6),3), NA, round(rnorm(3),3)),
  d3 = c(round(rnorm(2),3), rep(NA,2), round(rnorm(6),3)),
  d4 = c(round(rnorm(1),3), NA, round(rnorm(8),3))
)
table(droplevels(unlist(df2[1:4])[! unlist(df2[1:4]) %in% unlist(df2[1:4])[is.na(unlist(df2[5:8]))]]))
# F A 
# 5 4
```

Comment: No, sorry, this is not what I meant: I'd like to exclude from the frequency count only those  word *tokens* that have NA in the *corresponding* duration column. So one and the same word *type* (e.g., "A") may have NA duration in, say, `d1` but a value in, say, `d2`etc. That second token should be taken up in the frequency count but not the first one.

Comment: You're absolutely right: `table(unlist(replace(df[paste0("w", 1:4)], is.na(df[paste0("d", 1:4)]), NA)))` does work but only if the duration columns are converted to numeric! My apologies!

Comment: This works too (and is simpler): `table(df[paste0("w", 1:4)][!is.na(df[paste0("d", 1:4)])])`